# How to merge nodes that represent synonyms?

Tags: nlp, desktop-application, cytoscape, medical, pattern-synonyms

Suppose I have a graph like this:

[Cytoscape graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZObm.png)

The nodes 'lipid nanoparticle' and 'LNP' are synonyms. How can I identify nodes that represent synonyms and merge them in Cytoscape?

I searched Cytoscape App Store, but didn't manage to find a suitable app.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry -- I don't know of an app that would automatically detect synonyms and merge them.  You can certainly merge nodes using groups, but you would have to do that manually by selecting the two nodes, grouping them, and then collapsing them.  All of the edges for the two nodes would then connect (as meta-edges) to the group node.